# How to general skip a bad element when its optional with moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

iam using retrofit 2 with moshi and i have a problem when the optional nested class is broken.
Lets take this as a simple example:

```
class ClassA(val anyString: String, classB: ClassB?)

class ClassB(val firstString: String, val secondString: String)
```

I have a class A that has an optional Value from class B.
The Json that is gonna be parsed looks like this:

```
  {
   "anystring":"HelloWorld",
   "classB":{
      "firstString":"IamAFirstString"
      //SECOND STRING IS MISSING OR IS NULL
   }
}
```

When i try to parse this json ill get an exception:
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Non-null value 'secondString' was null at $.classB.secondString

What i want to archive is that i get the ClassA with an null value at classB because that value is optional so its okay when its null. I know that can archive this when i build an adapter and catch the exception but i want to know if theres a general way to archive this behaviour without creating an adapter for every json that i have to parse.